# Group Policy Preferences - Dynamic Environment Values

Tags: env

Is it possible to configure dynamic values within group policy preferences for environment variables?

I am trying to replace our old login scripts which set an env var according to the computer name.

set MYVAR=%CLIENTNAME:~-3%

Comment: It seems that %CLIENTNAME% is not supported by GPPs http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/afeb726a-b05c-408d-8eed-b71fea5ec29e/clientname-variable-not-working-in-gpo-preferences?forum=winserverGP